# How can I resize OS X 10.7 Lion display screen resolution during install?

Tags: macos, install, screen, resolution

I have a Mac Mini (2011) with no OS installed currently (drives are RAIDed and I lost Recovery HD partition).

When I boot, I start the Internet Recovery, which I am viewing through a Samsung P50 Plasma TV. The max. resolution of the TV is 1366x768 pixel. 
After Recovery begins, it tries to open the installer with a resolution of 1920x1080 pixel and won't let me access some parts of the screen. Unfortunately, that also includes the "Continue" button and progress bar to install Lion.

Is there any way I can force a smaller resolution or get the window to move, so I can start the installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into the same issue.  Followed YouTube video of installation in order to figure out the following:

Once the disc is booted, select Reinstall OS X.  You will then reach the screen where you cannot see the Continue button.  Using your keyboard, press TAB followed by SPACE.  You should then reach the User Agreement screen.  Press TAB, TAB, TAB and SPACE.  Click the Agree button which should be visible.  Click the installation drive and press TAB, TAB and SPACE.

This should get you to the point where Lion is installing.

Comment: Sounds appropriate, but I am unable to test. If this works for someone else, let me know and I can mark this as the answer.

Comment: The number of tabs was slightly different but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work on TV. I ended up just connecting to a monitor during install and then plugging into the TV after the desktop booted.

Answer (score -1):

Try holding down the shift key during boot. It works for some displays, but maybe not your TV.